# Access LocationManager callbacks from different activities android

Tags: android, android-activity, locationmanager

I would like to start the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) from one activity where updates are shown in text. But also allow the user to switch to the "map view" activity to see the progress on the map.

How might I go about allowing two separate activities to receive callbacks so I can update both activities?

Comment: Take a look at BroadcastReceivers and how to implement them

Comment: Run a service in the background that starts/stops the location listeners. Start/Stop that service with your app (or as needed from parts of your app). Then use a service bus to broadcast location updates. This works really really well and without a mess of listener/receivers. Check out Otto: https://github.com/square/otto (useful all over the place in Android, this is just one example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register for updates from a service which would then broadcast to your various activities what the location updates were, allowing multiple activities to see these updates without having to register each one for location updates.